# Simple system to track hours worked

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mariadb, raspberry-pi3, rfid

I am a total beginner and I think I underestimated my little project.

I am trying to implement a simple attendance system that will give me the hours worked per day and later per month.
I am using a Raspberry pi 3 b+ and RC522 Rfid reader plus 16x2 lcd display.
The data ist stored in a database using MariaDB.

The idea is to use it for student workers in a restaurant to clock in their hours.
The employees still write down their hours, but if it works it could replace the paperwork, we will see.
I know that there will be some concerns about legality, but thats up for the lawyers once I am done.

However my issue is, that right now I am unable to clock in and clock out multiple users.
It does work for one user.
If I clock in User 1 it waits until there is a new clock out info, doesn't matter which user it is.
So user 1 clock in, user 2 wants to clock in but he is registered to clock out and only then the database entry is transferred. I think it somehow would need to update the entries instantly.

I think you can get the idea from the picture
[phpMyAdminScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYbzw.jpg)

I think I need to get more info from the database and compare it to what I have.
But I hit a wall now and I am unable to find a solution for my problem.

The code I have right now:

```
'#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
import mysql.connector
import drivers


db = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="xxx",
  passwd="xxx",
  database="attendancesystem"
)

cursor = db.cursor()
reader = SimpleMFRC522()
display = drivers.Lcd()

sign_in = 0
sign_out= 1

try:
  while True:
    display.lcd_clear()
    display.lcd_display_string("Transponder", 1)
    display.lcd_display_string("platzieren", 2)
    id, text = reader.read()

    ts = time.time()
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d     %H:%M:%S')

    cursor.execute("Select id, name FROM users WHERE rfid_uid="+str(id))
    result = cursor.fetchone()

    display.lcd_clear()


    #if cursor.rowcount >= 1:
      #display.lcd_display_string("Willkommen " + result[1], 2)
      #cursor.execute("INSERT INTO attendance (user_id) VALUES (%s)", (result[0],) )

    if sign_in == 0:
      sign_in = (sign_in +1) % 2
      sign_out = (sign_out +1) % 2
      cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO attendance (user_id, clock_in, signed_in) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (result[0], timestamp, sign_in) )
      display.lcd_display_string(f"Angemeldet " + result[1], 1)

    elif sign_in == 1:
      sign_out = (sign_out +1) % 2
      sign_in = (sign_in +1) % 2
      cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO attendance (user_id, clock_out, signed_in) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (result[0], timestamp, sign_in) )
      display.lcd_display_string (f"Abgemeldet " + result[1], 1)
      db.commit()

    else:
      display.lcd_display_string("Existiert nicht.", 1)
    time.sleep(2)
finally:
  GPIO.cleanup()'
```

My idea was to get one more database entry called signed_in and either have it as 0 or as 1.
The signed_in status does update how I want it to, but I don't know how to continue from here.

And I fail to be able to update the table I want to.
My idea was to get user_id and check for this id the last status of the signed_in row, if it is 1 the timestamp will update the clock_out row and signed_in to 0.
If it is 0 and clock_out is not NULL it will start a new row with the clock_in timestamp and switch signed_in to 1.

I didn't have any luck with updating any database values, so I reverted back to INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the database would only store events. These events would be from when they touched the RFID. The card would have an ID/employee number.

Processing the database information would allow the calculation of who is on shift and the length of shifts worked etc.

[image]

If there was an odd number of entries for an employee then you could assume they are on shift. Even number of entries would mean they have completed the shift.

I don't have your hardware or database so I've created random RFID read events and used sqlite3.

```py
import datetime
import random
import sqlite3
import time


class SimpleMFRC522:
    @staticmethod
    def read():
        while random.randint(0, 30) != 10:  # Create some delay/blocking
            time.sleep(1)
        employee_id = random.randint(0, 5)
        return employee_id, f'employee_{employee_id}'


class MyDatabase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = sqlite3.connect('/tmp/my-test.db')
        with self.db:
            self.db.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS workers (
                        id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                        empl_no INTEGER,
                        name TEXT,
                        tap_event timestamp);
            """)
            self.db.commit()

    def insert_event(self, empl_no, name, timestamp):
        sqlite_insert_with_param = """INSERT INTO 'workers'
                                  ('empl_no', 'name', 'tap_event') 
                                  VALUES (?, ?, ?);"""
        self.db.cursor()
        self.db.execute(sqlite_insert_with_param, (empl_no, name, timestamp))
        self.db.commit()

    def worker_in(self, empl_no):
        sql_cmd = f"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM workers WHERE empl_no = {empl_no};"
        cursor = self.db.execute(sql_cmd)
        event_count, = cursor.fetchone()
        return event_count % 2 == 1 and event_count > 0

    def last_shift(self, empl_no):
        sql_cmd = f"""SELECT tap_event FROM 
                        (SELECT * FROM workers WHERE empl_no = {empl_no} ORDER BY tap_event DESC LIMiT 2) 
                        ORDER BY tap_event ASC ;"""
        cursor = self.db.execute(sql_cmd)
        tap_in, tap_out = cursor.fetchall()
        start = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(tap_in[0])
        end = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(tap_out[0])
        return end - start


def main():
    db = MyDatabase()
    reader = SimpleMFRC522()
    while True:
        empl_no, name = reader.read()
        print(f"adding tap event for {name}")
        db.insert_event(empl_no, name, datetime.datetime.timestamp(datetime.datetime.now()))
        if db.worker_in(empl_no):
            print(f"\t{name} has started their shift")
        else:
            time_worked = db.last_shift(empl_no)
            print(f"\t{name} has left the building after {time_worked}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This gave me a transcript as follows

```
adding tap event for employee_5
    employee_5 has started their shift
adding tap event for employee_0
    employee_0 has left the building after 0:02:10.154697
adding tap event for employee_3
    employee_3 has left the building after 0:07:02.465903
adding tap event for employee_3
    employee_3 has started their shift
adding tap event for employee_2
    employee_2 has left the building after 0:06:27.403874
adding tap event for employee_2
    employee_2 has started their shift
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try to implement or test it tomorrow.